# Conditional probability of check result

Tags: probability

> 1 out of 2000 has a disease. a check is accurate 95% of the times.
>   
>   Someone got a positive answer in the check, what the probability the he is sick?

Let $A$ be the event the check returns positive and $B$ the event the person is sick.

We are looking for $$P(B|A)={P(A|B)*P(B)\over P(A)}={\frac{95}{100}*\frac{1}{2000}\over P(A)}$$

Now we need to find $$P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B^\complement)*P(B^\complement)=\frac{95}{100}*\frac{1}{2000}+\frac{5}{100}*\frac{1999}{2000}\approx 0.05$$

So $$P(B|A)={\frac{95}{100}*\frac{1}{2000}\over 0.05}\approx 0.095$$

Does "a check is accurate 95% of the times"$=P(A|B)$?

Comment: By "one person got a positive answer", do you mean "all $2000$ were checked, and one got a positive answer"? Or do you mean what would more usually be expressed as "Someone got a positive answer", i.e. one person was checked and got a positive answer and nothing is implied about the others?

Comment: This is a fairly well documented problem. See, for example, http://vassarstats.net/bayes.html

Comment: @joriki "Someone got a positive answer"

Comment: I am not sure, but "a check is accurate 95% of the times" could mean: there is a probability of $0.95$ that the outcome of the check matches the reality. If chances are the same for positive and negative (in both cases a chance $0.95$ of matching reality) then there is a probability of $0.95$ that the person that received a positive answer is indeed sick.

Comment: @drhab: The $0.95$ is a general property of the test; every individual time it is applied, it yields the correct result with probability $0.95$. That's a completely different probability from the one being sought here, which is a conditional probability given the information that $1$ out of $2000$ has the disease. (Presumably it's being implied that the tested person has been uniformly randomly selected from a population in which $1$ in $2000$ have the disease; i.e. this is meant to set up the problem so that the *a priori* probability of disease before applying the test is $1$ in $2000$.)

Comment: @joriki Thank you for your explanation.